# Can TrueCrypt be configured to dismount volumes when you hibernate?

Tags: windows, security, encryption, truecrypt, disk-encryption

TrueCrypt can be configured to dismount volumes upon logoff but is it possible to dismount volumes when you hibernate windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In preferences under Auto-Dismount (in version 7.0a), in addition to "User logs off" there are also options for "Screen saver is launched" and, more to the point for your purposes, "Entering power saving mode" - I would think that would work for your purposes?

Comment: Good call!  It was right in front of me and I didn't see it.  Thanks!